# wont let me run rails s because there is another server running but i don't know how to access that server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I close the old server even though I can't see its terminal anymore so I can access my project?

I tried exiting out of the program then exiting back in but nothing would work.
keeps bringing up this error:

> A server is already running. Check C:/Users/Nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Nathans First project/tmp/pids/server.pid.
>   Exiting

Comment: use netstat to find the process id running on the port the server has bound to. Then kill that process.

Comment: I do this in the computers command prompt, correct? im very sorry, i just started coding a week ago.

Comment: yes you do it on the command line. cmd.exe to be exact.

Comment: it keeps telling me that the request needs "elevation"

Comment: run cmd.exe as administrator.

Comment: Brutal solution is reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Use netstat to find the process id running on the port the server has bound to. Then kill that process.

run `cmd.exe` as administrator.

To list process

```
C:\> netstat -a -b
```

Find the process id that is bound to the port your server runs on

```
C:\> Taskkill /PID <the process id (pid) of the server> /F
```

Answer (score 0):

can you visit your app from the url 127.0.0.1:3000, 3000 is the port your app suppose to be running.

Case 1. if you can visit at the location, then use the activity monitor or something like that , find the ruby process and kill it.

Case 2. if you can not visit, then just delete the file C:/Users/Nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Nathans First project/tmp/pids/server.pid will be fixed this problem. It is cause by a abnormal server exist like you shutdown your computer without shutdown the server normally.

Answer (score 0):

Check you tmp/pids/server.pid file under your app which wil have the process id of other instance of rails server currently running. First kill that process using kill -9 process_id in your linux terminal. Check how to kill a process for your particular version

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `server.pid` file in the `C:/Users/Nathan/Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Nathans First project/tmp/pids/` directory and restart the `server`.

Make sure you close the command prompt window and open it again before restarting the server.

Hope this helps!